# Как задать два background?

Tags: css, css3, background

Привет подскажите пожалуйста такой код. Именно код ибо суть я знаю а вот код неправильно пишу.
один блок
надо задать background, левая сторона 50% черный цвет остальные 50% картинкой. Игрался с кодом, нифига, поможете надеюсь)

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

body:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://mediad.publicbroadcasting.net/p/kalw/files/styles/medium/public/201601/Nature-Brain.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А как нужно чтобы картинка себя вела? Можно например просто перекрыть 50% черным цветом картинки, которая сама по себе на весь блок растянута.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), url(https://massaget.kz/userdata/uploads/u61377/1415712179_l.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```